# Where to put the file.close() in loops in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple program it is supposed to search a text file for the word 'why' and print how many times it comes up. Here is the code:

```
def get():
    a = 0
    target = str(raw_input('name file > '))
    file = open(target,'r+')
    main(file)

def main(target):
    for x in target:
        if x == 'why':
           a+= 1 

    print a

file.close()

get()
```

But where am I supposed to put the `file.close()`? Do I need to put it in the for loop inside the main() or can I just put it at the end of the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do `file.close()` after you're finished working with the file. So here, it would be best to do it after the for-loop.

```
def main(target):for x in target:
    if x == 'why':
        a+= 1 
    file.close()
    print a
```

Alternatively, you can do `with open('file.txt', 'r+') as f` which automatically closes the file (and is more pythonic):

```
def get():
    a = 0
    target = str(raw_input('name file > '))
    with open(target,'r+') as myfile:
        main(myfile)

def main(target):
    for x in target:
        if x == 'why':
            a+= 1  
    print a

get()
```

So here, after main() has finished, the file will automatically close.

---

Just note that you shouldn't name your variable `file`, as that is already a built-in function, so you are just overriding it.

Also, there's no need to call `str()` around `raw_input()` :). `raw_input` already returns a string.

---

And finally, your error will actually raise an UnboundLocalError, because `a` is only defined in the `get()` function. If you want to access it in other functions, put `global a` before you define the variable :).

Comment: Using `with` is Pythonic.

Comment: Note that `x == 'why'` will always evaluate to `False` because `for x in target` iterates over each *line* in `target`. I've added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17659986/78845) that addresses this.

Answer (score 0):

The Pythonic way of managing an open [`file`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) object is to use [the `with` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement). This will close the `file` at the end of the block. Since [`file`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) is a Python built-in (and given you don't want to append to the file), a fixed-up version of your `get()` function may look like this:

```
def get():
    filename = raw_input('name file > ')
    with open(filename, 'r') as source:
        main(source)
```

Note that `x == 'why'` will always evaluate to `False` because `for x in target` iterates over each *line* in `target`, leaving on the newline character. You shall need [`strip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) this off if you want to compare the whole line. A fixed-up version of your `main()` might look like this:

```
def main(target):
    print sum(line.strip() == 'why' for line in target)
```

If you want to [`count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count) the occurrences of each `why` on each line then `sum(line.count('why') for line in target)` may be a better approach.

Last, if you want to `import` this file (say into a suite of unit-tests!), then you should protect your call to (the ambiguously-named) `get()` function with [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/78845)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    get()
```